# Custom Export from power BI service

Tags: export, csv, python, r, powerbi

I'm trying to make a custom button that exports filtered tables to a csv and downloads them to my computer. I am aware that you can do this with the '...' button but this functionality is for other users that have requested this custom button. I was able to write an R script that achieves this in Power BI Desktop but I need this to work in Power BI Service. The way the desktop version is currently implemented is by using a button that goes to an 'Export' page that runs the R-script that downloads the filtered table as a csv. If anyone has any idea how I might run a script that exports and downloads tables as csv's from Power BI Service I would really appreciate it.